# Flyway exception with flyway.clean() - Can't drop without CASCADE specification

Tags: flyway, hana

While using `flyway.clean()` - 
I get the following error:

> Message    : SAP DBTech JDBC: [417]: can't drop without CASCADE
>   specification: cannot drop table referenced by foreign key.

Is there a way to make Flyway cascade drop all objects?

Comment: what Flyway version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug. Please file an issue in the issue tracker including the smallest possible bit of SQL that triggers this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop tables that have foreign key constraints on SAP HANA you either have to drop those constraints before or you have to specify the `CASCADE` command option.
This is documented in the [SAP HANA SQL reference guide](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/20d7fd287519101480afbce1b997e4b9.html).
Note, that `CASCADE` will drop all dependent objects, not just constraints.

Comment: That's what I first tought but according to the Flyway documentation `clean` should manage to drop all tables in the correct order so that error should not appear. This is why I +1 @axel-fontaine answer. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/clean